# Link in routerlink does not change

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I am creating a sidebar with links on it. I have 3 components, the sidebar component links 2 toolbar components so that I can have menu button every time I would hide the sidebar.

This is on my sidebar component.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
        [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
        [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'side' : 'side'"
        [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
      <mat-toolbar>Cust_Corp</mat-toolbar>
      <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="container">
          <p><a routerLink="/cust-toolnav">Home</a></p>
          <p><a routerLink="/cust-regform">Create a customer</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Display a customer</a></p> 
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <app-cust-toolnav [title]="title" [burgerMenu]="isHandset$ | async" (burgerClick)="drawer.toggle()"></app-cust-toolnav>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <app-cust-regform [title]="title" [burgerMenu]="isHandset$ | async" (burgerClick)="drawer.toggle()"></app-cust-regform>
    </mat-sidenav-content>  

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I have a  for my 2nd toolbar. Every time I click the links, the url changes but the toolbar body does not change.

```
          <p><a routerLink="/cust-toolnav">Home</a></p>
          <p><a routerLink="/cust-regform">Create a customer</a></p>
```

I have check app-routing module to include

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustToolnavComponent } from './cust-toolnav/cust-toolnav.component';
import { CustRegformComponent } from './cust-regform/cust-regform.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'cust-toolnav', pathMatch: 'full' }, <-- I tried removing / and adding /.
  { path: 'cust-toolnav', component: CustToolnavComponent },
  { path: 'cust-regform', component: CustRegformComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: try like this [routerLink]="['/cust-toolnav']"

Comment: I think the issue is with  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: I tried that also and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have are implementing sidenav wrongly.
It should have only  1 `<mat-sidenav-content>` and place router-outlet inside `<mat-sidenav-content>`

Comment: I tried it only one but it has the same problem. I have two components that uses the same control to the button on the sidenav.